# Regular Expression - Remove zeroes inside an expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to remove leading zeroes from the numerical part of an expression (using .net 2.0 C# Regex class).

Ex:

> PAR0000034 -> PAR34
>
> WP0003204 -> WP3204

I tried the following:

```
//keep starting characters, get rid of leading zeroes, keep remaining digits
string result = Regex.Replace(inputStr, "^(.+)(0+)(/d*)", "$1$3", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Obviously, it did not work. I need a bit of help to find the mistake.

Comment: The escape is not a forward slash `/`, it is supposed to be backwards ``\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for that, the `Split` method can do that for you.

Splitting on `'0'`, removing empty entries (i.e. between the mulitple zeroes), and limiting the result to two strings will give you the two strings before and after the leading zeroes. Then you just put those two strings together again:

```
string result = String.Concat(
  input.Split(new char[] { '0' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
);
```

Comment: -1 this doesn't work for AB001002 and other inputs having two consequent non-leading zeroes..

Comment: @MichalKlouda: You are mistaken. It works just fine, try it for yourself. With the input `"AB001002"` the result is `"AB1002"`.

Comment: @MichalKlouda - Note the `, 2`.

Comment: @Guffa oh I see, sorry about that, changing -1 to +1 ;)

Answer (score 3):

In your expression the `.*` part is greedy, so it catches full string. Further
use backslash instead of slash for digit `\d`

```
string result = Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"^([^0]+)(0+)(\d*)", "$1$3");
```

Or use look behind instead:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(inputStr, "(?<=[a-zA-Z])0+", "");
```

Comment: Good catch, still the xpression doesn't work. The result of this expression still does modify the input str in anyway.

Comment: You can simplify that to `Regex.Replace(inputStr, @"^([^0]+)0+", "$1")`. `IgnoreCase` really does nothing here.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Regex.Replace("PPP00001001", "([^0]*)0+(.*)", "$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "leading zeroes" is confusing, since the zeroes you're talking about aren't actually at the beginning of the string. But if I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(inputStr, "^(.*?)0+", "$1");
```

There are actually several ways to do it, with and without regex, but the above is probably the shortest and easiest to understand. The important part is the `.*?` lazy quantifier. This will ensure that it a) finds only the first string of zeroes, and b) deletes all the "leading" zeroes in the string.

Comment: What I meant by leading zeroes, is leading the digits in anyway after the alpha chars. Thanks that worked. One quick question: What does the $1 in the replace function do, could not find a good answer to that.

Comment: The `$1` means "whatever was matched inside the first pair of parentheses," which in this case is `(.*?)`. So when you use it on `PAR0000034`, the regex matches `PAR00000`, then throws out the `00000` and keeps `PAR`.